# pandas add row numbers after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

My dataframe includes three columns: identifier columns `A` and `B`, their combination gives a unique identifier, a `Date` column which I need to sort by order within each identifier. After sort and groupby, I wish to add a column with the row number within each group.

```
df
A       B      Date
cat    CityA   2014-08-05
cat    CityA   2012-09-14
cat    CityA   1972-10-15
dog    CityC   1999-12-01
dog    CityC   1997-09-23 
dog    CityC   1995-12-19
```

Now, this code has group by `A` and `B` and sort `Date`, how can I add the row number?

```
grouped = df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'Date'],
                  ascending=[True, True, False]).groupby(['A','B'])
```

```
Expected df
A       B      Date         rowNumber
cat    CityA   2014-08-05   1
cat    CityA   2012-09-14   2
cat    CityA   1972-10-15   3
dog    CityC   1999-12-01   1
dog    CityC   1997-09-23   2
dog    CityC   1995-12-19   3
```

Comment: What you mean by row number ? 1 to n or count number of row per group

Comment: 1 to n per group. I added the expected df @BENY. Thanks

Comment: I have the solution for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us do it within two steps, I list both total count and cum count

```
out = df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'Date'],
                  ascending=[True, True, False])
out['row number'] = out.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
out['count number'] = out.groupby(['A','B'])['Date'].transform('count')
```

Comment: The row number starts from 0. Is there a way to start from 1?